# Get 'keys' and 'input text' from *ngfor to .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

i have to create a string with the keys that are dynamically created by *ngfor, and input text by the user.

i find it hard to explain, heres some code and what i need

```
<th *ngFor="let column of Filter" >
    <tr>{{ column.name }}: <input type="{{column.type}}" id="{{ column.key }}" name="{{ column.key }}" autocomplete="off"  > &nbsp;</tr>
</th>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="fFilter(string)">Search</button>
```

i want that the string is: " *column.key1='input1', column.key2='input2'* .. " and so on until there's no columns..

I was trying to find a solution, but nones helps me..
How can i do this? Sorry for not being able to explain it the best way.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to understand your requirement and created the solution.

As per my understanding, you have user controls(shown in the image below) generated using code mentioned here:

```
    <th *ngFor="let column of Filter" >
      <tr>{{ column.name }}: 
      <input type="{{column.type}}" id="{{ column.key }}" 
             name="{{ column.key }}" autocomplete="off" 
            [(ngModel)]="column.value" > &nbsp;</tr>
    </th>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="fFilter()">Search</button>
```

[image: User controls generated from above code]
[image: data input]
After entering data in all textboxes, when the user clicks on the search you want to output or data as shown in alert in below image inside the function call.
[image: On click of search alert shown]

I have added [(ngModel)]="column.value" for two way binding of each textbox data. We can get those data inside .ts file.

Column.model.ts:

```
export class Column{
   public key:string;
   public type:string;
   public name:string;
   public value:string;
    constructor(key:string,type:string,name:string,value:string)
    {
        this.key=key;
        this.type=type;
        this.name=name;
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Column } from './Column';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  column: Column;
  Filter: Column[]=[new Column("1","ABC","Column1",""),
  new Column("2","ABC","Column2",""),
  new Column("3","ABC","Column3",""),
  new Column("4","ABC","Column4","")];
  constructor() { 
 // this.Filter=new Column(id="",type="",name="")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  fFilter(){
    var requiredValue="";
    this.Filter.map(
      x=>requiredValue+=(x.key+"="+x.value+",")
    );
    alert(requiredValue);
  }
}
```

Basically, I have changed the way of passing an argument from HTML file to typescript file, but get the same data in fFilter() function which you can use as per your requirement.

Comment: That's exactly what i need!! But im not getting the column.key and what i type on input text boxes like you example ( 1="Apple"2="Banana"... ), I'm getting what's in constructor.. what am i missing? thank you for your help, it's taking me to the solution i need!

Comment: You need to add [(ngModel)]="column.value" in your html code, check my html code mentioned above.

Comment: my code looks like this:
<tr>{{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key | translate}}: <input type="{{column.type}}" id="{{ column.key }}" name="{{ column.key }}" autocomplete="off"  [(ngModel)]="column.value" >  </tr>

Comment: Have you checked my .ts file code? If you have used two-way binding and getting data like I have mentioned in "fFilter()" function, you will definitely get it. Verify it again and if you will not be able to do then share your HTML and ts file code.

Comment: If it is the proper answer to your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I've posted my code, what's missing? 
Shouldn't i be givig "Filter" the column values instead of construct new columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176420/discussion-between-riddhi-and-bruno).

Answer (score 1):

My code looks like this, the funtion called on html just maps the columns created on .ts side.. i think im missing something between html and .ts that passes the values that i want (column.key - input value)

**html:**

```
<th *ngFor="let column of entityList.metadata.advancedFilter" >
     <tr>{{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key | translate}}: <input type="{{column.type}}" id="{{ column.key }}" name="{{ column.key }}" autocomplete="off"  [(ngModel)]="column.value" >  </tr>
</th>
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="advancedFilter()">Search</button>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
...
import { Column} from '../../models/entity-list.model';
...
export class EntityListComponent implements OnInit {

    column: Column;
    Filter: Column[]=[new Column("code","text","Column1",""),
        new Column("title","text","Column2",""),
        new Column("description","text","Column3",""),
        new Column("entryDate","date","Column4",""),
        new Column("endSubmissionDate","date","Column4","")];

....

    advancedFilter(){
        var requiredValue="where ";
        this.Filter.map(
            x=>requiredValue+=(x.key+"="+"'"+x.value+"'"+" AND ")
        );
        requiredValue = requiredValue.slice(0, -5);
        alert(requiredValue+";");
    }
```

**entity-list.model.ts**

```
...
export class Column{
    public key:string;
    public type:string;
    public name:string;
    public value:string;
    constructor(key:string,type:string,name:string,value:string)
    {
        this.key=key;
        this.type=type;
        this.name=name;
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

My output:
[image]